# Count elements and show/update value of current in view + total

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, counting, figure

I am trying to understand how to count and display current and total number of figures on my page.

My html

```
<div class="is-vertical">
<figure><img src="src.jpg"><figcaption class="wp-element-caption">Towers Day<br>NYC</figcaption></figure>
<figure><img src="src.jpg"><figcaption class="wp-element-caption">Towers Day<br>NYC</figcaption></figure>
<figure><img src="src.jpg"><figcaption class="wp-element-caption">Towers Day<br>NYC</figcaption></figure>
</div>
```

My js attempt of trying to get the total number

```
var totalItems = $( ".is-vertical figure" ).length;
```

My js attempt of trying to display the variable in an appended span

```
$('.is-vertical').append('<span class="numbers">')+totalItems.join('</span>');
    
});
```

For the last part of showing the current one I am wondering if one could use ($(window).scrollTop() somehow and update the value of the current figure in view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up solved by this script:

```
var $isVertical = $('.is-vertical'); // <div class="is-vertical">
var $numbersSpan = $('<span>', { class: 'numbers', text: 'Figure 1 of ' + $isVertical.find('figure').length });
$isVertical.prepend($numbersSpan);

// Function to update the current figure number
function updateCurrentFigureNumber() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var scrollTop = $isVertical.scrollTop();
  var figureHeight = $isVertical.find('figure').height();
  
  // Calculate the current figure number in view
  var currentFigureNumber = Math.floor((scrollTop + windowHeight * 0.75) / figureHeight) + 1;
  
  // Update the text inside the 'numbers' span
  $numbersSpan.text( + currentFigureNumber + ' / ' + $isVertical.find('figure').length);
}

// Add an event listener to update the current figure number when scrolling
$isVertical.scroll(updateCurrentFigureNumber);

// Call the updateCurrentFigureNumber function initially to set the correct figure number
updateCurrentFigureNumber();
```

Answer (score 1):

To construct a jQuery element, you need the following structure:

```js
$('<span>', { class: 'numbers', text: figureCount });
```

Alternatively:

```js
$('<span>').addClass('numbers').text(figureCount);
```

#### Working example

```js
const $isVertical = $('.is-vertical'); // <div class="is-vertical">
const figureCount = $isVertical.find('figure').length; // 3

$isVertical.append($('<span>', { class: 'numbers', text: figureCount }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="is-vertical">
  <figure><img src="src.jpg">
    <figcaption class="wp-element-caption">Towers Day<br>NYC</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure><img src="src.jpg">
    <figcaption class="wp-element-caption">Towers Day<br>NYC</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure><img src="src.jpg">
    <figcaption class="wp-element-caption">Towers Day<br>NYC</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: that's working super well! Thank you. How would I go about if I wanted to update that value to also display the current number. Picture each figure is 100vh for instance... could I do something like:     `$(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.is-vertical figure').offset().top){
// Update value`
} });